# Can JavaSparkContext create JavaRDD from Queue(Collection API)

Tags: java, apache-spark

I need to implement Apache Spark in existed backend application.
For storing objects in our application we use BlockingQueue and we put objects in this queue during app runs. It means, that all objects which will put to queue after executing commant javaSparkContext.parallelize(myOwnList) wont be available in Spark Topology.

So, for implementing Spark I have to find solutions for next 2 points:

1. How I can create JavaRDD from this queue? We can create JavaRDD from file, List..., but not from queue. Should I use List instead?
2. How to provide to Spark new objects which were put to Collection after executing javaSparkContext.parallelize(myOwnList). Should I use patter Observer to run Spark Topology when objects were put to List?

1 question - I can use List, but I need to try to save usage for BlockingQueue
2 question - It's difficult to implement pattern Observer in our source code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.